# How to automate multiple test

Tags: automated-tests, casperjs

I'm using casperjs to run so front end tests. I'm trying to figure out the best way to automate the execution of tests. I need a way to launch 5 separate files, and detect any time there is a FAIL, not sure how to best do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I ended up writing my own shell script, which is run automatically.

```
> output
for f in *.js
do
    echo "starting test"
    casperjs test $f >> output
done

if grep "FAIL" output 
    then echo "error occured"
    else echo "test was successful"
fi
```

that is a simplified version, you can have it email on fail, etc.